# Are there elastic materials that are transparent to infrared light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, infrared-radiation, optical-materials

I am working on a device that I want to be encased in an elastic membrane to allow for articulation and water resistance. This means that all sensors must be inside the membrane. The membrane must then be transparent to visible or infrared light. I do not need crystal clear video.

Comment: Visible OR infrared? The title ask for IR but the text suggests visible it is just fine.

Comment: Either would work but the examples of materials that transmit visible light that i have seen are still pretty blurry.

Comment: Then other to invite you to consider rubber plastic  already used to encapsulate items such as toys (it should be an easy search) I can only add that for infrared it can be a difficult if not impossible task.

Comment: Consider also this site https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/plastic-thats-transparent-to-ir-range-sensors